# Java REST API CLient

Tags: java, api, rest, apiclient

I have java client that hits API which i have created but when i run the class which is basically java client then it throws exception.
Here is exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 405
    at TST.main(TST.java:29)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TST {

    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-FileUpload/rest/files/upload");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        String input = "/home/hassan/Downloads/56963a249bff5_4__67_green-lantern_issue70.png";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }

    }

}
```

I am testing it on local host i have also tried to write my IP Address in place of localhost but it does not worked it also throw the same exception.

URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.3:8080/JAXRS-FileUpload/rest/files/upload");

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exception? Can we see a stacktrace?

Comment: I have edited my question and added exception there

Comment: Can you change the content type image/png and give a try?

Comment: You should have a look at the logs of the side where the API runs and show us the code of that side too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource you are trying to access is not there, or does not allow `POST`. You could try with `GET` to see if it is there. If not, it should return a `404`.

`405` return code means "Method not allowed", can be seen in some cases when the resource is simply missing. `404` means "Not Found".

Comment: thanks i used GET method in API now i changed it to       POST but know it throws another exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 200
 at TST.main(TST.java:29)

Comment: That is actually a success code. `200` means OK. In your code you check only for "HTTP_CREATED", which is `201`. Every `2xx` code is actually a success response, so you shouldn't throw an exception for them. Some more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Yes this resolve my issue i have commented the code which actually throws exception but if i want to throw exception other than 2xx then what should i do.

Comment: There are no utility methods for that as far as I know, the easiest would be: `if (conn.getResponseCode()/100 > 2) { throw the exception }`